# ResultSet.insertRow() VS Statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO..."). Which is better to use?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, resultset

When inserting or updating data in DB (Oracle DB in my case) using Java, which is better to use:

- `ResultSet.insertRow()`, `ResultSet.updateRow()` or
- `Statement.executeUpdate(....)`

Most of the time I use `rs.insertRow()` and `rs.updateRow()`, in that way avoiding the need to write queries, but is that justified performance-wise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never do anything with `ResultSet` except walk through it, map it into objects or data structures, and close it.    If I want to INSERT, I do it with `PreparedStatement`.  My `ResultSets` never stick around long enough to be modified.  I prefer to keep persistence operations short so I can close the connection as quickly as possible.  I think this approach scales better, because it's easier for multiple users to share pooled connections that way.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @duffymo. You were quite right, ResultSets are sure hard to track and manage, thats one of their biggest downsides imo.

Comment: The tracking is easier if you keep them in the scope of a single method: create them, map out the data, and close them in a finally block.  You won't leak resources that way.  SQL artifacts should never leak outside your persistence layer.

Comment: Thats very true but what I meant was that if I happen to forget an open ResultSet then its very difficult to find it in order to close it,  especially if the application is very big. So far I haven't discovered any reasonable method to track down open ResultSets.

Comment: If you do it all in the scope of one method it's easier to find and fix.  If you use Spring SimpleJdbcTemplate, the problem will be taken care of for you.  Your application might be "big", but that's why you layer these things.  It's like neighborhoods in New York City: sure there are millions of people, but you're only concerned with your block.

Answer (score 0):

I think part of it is how large is the resultset.  If you are looping through 3 million records, I would use the rs.updateRow() rather than executing a query 3 million times.